# Replace all buttons with other(s)

Tags: javascript, button, replace

I would like to have vanilla JS script, which replaces ALL buttons selected with class, by another button, also selected by class.

Idea is, when I press Replace button, all "123" buttons with class "red" would be replaced into buttons with buttons "456" class "blue" (ideally replace would be toggleable).

I literally need to replace buttons, not just switch classes.

Any idea?

```
<html>
<body>

<button class="red">123</button>
<button class="red">123</button>
<button class="red">123</button>

<br>
<br>

<button class="blue">456</button>

<br>
<br>

<button onclick="replace">Replace</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function replace() {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("red")].forEach(function(el) {
    el.outerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("blue")[0].outerHTML
  })
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button class="red">123</button>
  <button class="red">123</button>
  <button class="red">123</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="blue">456</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="replace()">Replace</button>
</body>

</html>
```